# Cut Function: Making Irregular cuts in R

Tags: r, cut

I need to use the cut function to divide into irregular, uneven breaks.

I need to cut into ranges such as 1 to 15, 16 to 19, 20 to 45... ect.  Though I do not know how to do this or if it is possible.  Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?cut` is a good first step...

Here is a sample from which you can build:

```
# create a long vector that you want to cut
z <- rnorm(10000)
# create a vector with irregular breakpoints
breaks <- c( -6, -1, 1, 3, 6 )
# cut the long vector, look at the `table()`d result
table( cut( z, breaks ) )
  (-6,-1]  (-1,1]   (1,3]   (3,6] 
     1572    6806    1608      14
```